# how to map nested List to another List with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper, dto

I am using Latest version of Auto Mapper `6.1.0'`.
I have  `Poll` and `PolOption` Tables like below:

```
public class Poll
{
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Title { get; set; }
      public string Body { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<PollOption> Options { get; set; }
}

public class PollOption 
{
   public virtual string Title { get; set; }
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int PollId { get; set; }
   public virtual Poll Poll { get; set; }
}
```

and I have two `viewModels` for these Models  Like :

```
public class EditPollViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public List<PollOptionViewModel> Options { get; set; }
}
public  class PollOptionViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

}
```

I am using this for Auto Mapper config :

```
config.CreateMap<Poll, EditPollViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.Options, src => src.MapFrom(t => t.Options));
```

but when I am runing project With below code I have gotten Error .

```
 return Mapper.Map<EditPollViewModel>(model);
```

I have gotten this error :

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: PollOption -> PollOptionViewModel
>
> PollOption ->
>
> PollOptionViewModel

Comment: add this `CreateMap<PollOption , PollOptionViewModel>().ReverseMap()` and try again.

Comment: I have tried that but the result was same

Comment: you do map `PollOption` to `PollOptionViewModel` ! but this does not exist in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you don't need map members that have the same name like `Options` to `Options` Automapper do this Automatically and you forget to map  `PollOption` to `PollOptionViewModel`:

```
config.CreateMap<PollOption , PollOptionViewModel>().ReverseMap()
```

and change

```
public List<PollOptionViewModel> Options { get; set; }
```

to

```
public ICollection<PollOptionViewModel> Options { get; set; }
```

also add  `ReverseMap()` in your map:

```
config.CreateMap<Poll, EditPollViewModel>().ReverseMap()
```

Comment: good . thank you Saeed . could you tell me about `ReverseMap` Method ?

Comment: By calling `ReverseMap`, AutoMapper creates a reverse mapping configuration that includes unflattening. [see more](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening).